# django-tastypie usage without model

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I need to POST data via AJAX-request to backend python function (that data will be processed with third-party python script) and use the result in the frontend. Currently I am using django-tastypie for API (I am using only ModelResource for my Models). As I understand, I can use Resource to implement this behaviour, but I am a little confused because I don't want to save or store any data, I just want to procced it in the backend. Should I use django-tastypie or maybe it is better to choose another method?

Comment: Are you saying you POST your ajax to a tastypie resource endpoint? Do you use django views at all or tastypie only?

Comment: @ShangWang I have both django views and tastypie api. I don't know how to do that better.

Comment: I think posting your ajax data to a django view would be straightforward enough if you are not so familiar with tastypie. There are tons of examples to show you how to do that if you are not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prepend_urls` for this

**prepend_urls** -> A hook for adding your own URLs or matching before the default URLs. Useful for adding custom endpoints or overriding the built-in ones. [Tastypie docs link](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#prepend-urls)

See below code

```
class YourModelResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = YourModel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'your_model'

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/do_some_work%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('do_some_work'), name="api_do_some_work"),
        ]

    def do_some_work(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
        self.is_authenticated(request)

        #Call the script and get the results
        results = []

        result_list = {
            'results': results,
        }

        return self.create_response(request, result_list)
```

Here `prepend_urls` method is overridden to call a nested resource `do_some_work`. The URI for this call will be like this

```
/api/v1/your_model/do_some_work/
```

Above method is suggested if you have to use Tastypie other wise Django views will be best option for this scenario.